# Fixnum.times { image_tag('path_to_file') } returns the fixnum

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I was trying to refactor my erb code for rating stars into one line and came across this, is it possible to achieve the results another way?

So currently it's like this

```
<% rating.times do %>
  <%= image_tag 'rating_star.png' %>
<% end %>
```

Ideally I'd like to reduce this to

```
<%= rating.times { image_tag 'rating_star.png' } %>
```

This returns the value of rating (0, 1, 2, 3, 4 or 5), if I change `<%=` to `<%` nothing is rendered. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`concat`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TextHelper.html#method-i-concat):

```
<% rating.times { concat image_tag('rating_star.png') } %>
```

But `<%= ... %>` within a loop is cleaner IMO.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Yes I agree placing it inside a block is cleaner

Answer (score 2):

You need `#map` to return an array of all `image_tags` you wish.
Then `#join` the result to get a string.
Lastly, you need to tell this string is valid html with `#html_safe`.

```
<%= rating.times.map{ image_tag 'rating_star.png' }.join.html_safe %>
```

Comment: The code I posted for multiple lines works fine, it's just when I put it into a block I'm having issues

Comment: the problem was you were lacking `#map` I updated my answer to use a oneliner

Comment: This renders the result as an array  `["<img alt=\"Star\" src=\"/assets/star.png\" />", "<img alt=\"Star\" src=\"/assets/star.png\" />", "<img alt=\"Star\" src=\"/assets/star.png\" />", "<img alt=\"Star\" src=\"/assets/star.png\" />", "<img alt=\"Star\" src=\"/assets/star.png\" />"]`

Comment: ah yes of course, you will need to `#join` the result with the separator you wish

Comment: Nearly, just needed .html_safe too. Thanks

Comment: and you definitely need `<%= %>` tag instead of `<% %>` tag to render it in the html.

Comment: oh yes, I was too quick in my copy paste, thanks for pointing that out

Answer (score 0):

The difference between `<% %>` and `<%= %>` is that the former is simply evaluated, but with the latter the result is rendered.  You have two things going on in your code snippet:  the *control* part (the loop), and the *rendering* part (the image tag).  Since you want only the image tag part rendered, you want to surround only that code with `<=% %>`, and the rest with `<% %>`.

So while this would work:

```
<%= rating.times { %> <%= image_tag 'rating_star.png' %> <% } %>
```

I find it much less readable than the 3-line version.